# help figuring out how to replace/repair this component

Tags: power-supply, usb

[image: Picture of board]

The micro-USB jack in this board is broken and I was trying to figure out how to replace this entire thing. The micro-USB is for power/charging and the bigger USB has unknown functionality that we've never used.

As far as I can tell, this takes power from the micro-USB into a ribbon cable that plugs into the actual mainboard. plus whatever the USB-A does (output ?).

My goal is just to replace the power supply. However, it is impossibly hard to google and find any off-the-shelf component like this.

Anyone have any suggestions ? I am fine with wiring up a completely different USB power jack to this or the mainboard.

Comment: Whats wrong with desoldering the broken and soldering in a new one?

Comment: That is an option if I can't find an easier way, since I have never soldered something this tiny.

Comment: "this tiny"? I thought we ware talking about the micro usb connector, or is there something on the other side of the board that needs to be done?

Comment: Yeah that Micro-USB connector should be pretty easy to remove and replace. It appears to be all metal, so it would be hard to damage the new on through over-heating. Just watch you don't lean your iron back into the ribbon cable connector and melt it.

Answer (score 1):

If the u-B receptacle is broken inside (broken plasic an/or bent/folded contacts), you need to replace this part.

This seems to be a through-hole mount u-B connector (for good mechanical durability), which would be really difficult to remove without some damage to PCB, even if you have a hot-air "pencil" like this one,

[image]

Another tool is a small propane torch, but you will need to be very-very careful not to burn your board.

There is a more safe method to remove the connector. You need to get a miniature shear cutter, and accurately cut the connector housing into pieces, down to short remnants near each soldered-through mounting hole/slot. After you remove the bulk of connector's shroud, de-solder each signal pin one-by-one, and then de-solder each piece of shield one by one with a regular soldering iron (with sufficient power), helping to remove the pieces with tweezers.

You should be able to find a replacement part of exactly the same shroud mounting shape on Digi-Key or similar places, look for USB connector, then "micro-B receptacle", you will have a hundred of variants.

And have a good luck.